# Jenkins + Artifactory: Failure in post build SCM action: Cannot commit

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I created a Maven Project within Jenkins the configuration you can find below.
After everything configured within Artifactory, I can build the snapshots without any issue. Only after I set the build to be staged for release( [image: staging]) I get an error that there is something wrong within the SCM settings (see Error Log). I checked the "Additional Behaviours" but could not find the right solution for to fix this error.

Any suggestion to fix this?
Thanks in Advance!

## Error

the final part of the error log
[image: the final part of the error log]

## Git

[image: Git]

## Build Environment

[image: Build Environment image description here]

## Post build

[image: Post build]

Comment: Can you please check if the user, email and password that you are using are being injected to the git commit process?

Comment: Within the console log on line 8 i can see: "using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials " but no where else in the console log credentials are mentioned.  I also tried overriding the git Git credentials within the "Artifactory Release Staging" setting, no succes.

Comment: Adding the following [logger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-LogsinJenkins) can help you investigating the git problem: "org.jfrog.hudson.release.maven.MavenReleaseWrapper"

Comment: Thx Dima Nevelev that helped. It told me that it didn't know who I was. So I added my Git credentials to my global settings.

Comment: is branch you specified actually available in the git repo?